# Getting Nodes within NodeList XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xmlnode, xmlnodelist

Okay so I haven't worked much with XML, and I'm trying to retrieve values between certain tags from an XML Rest Response.
The XML Response is as follows:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root version="1.1" result="Success">
    <row>
        <NewUsed>used</NewUsed>
        <Make>TOYOTA</Make>
        <Model>HILUX</Model>
        <Derivative>3.0 D-4D Double Cab Raider</Derivative>
        <MMCode>60036426</MMCode>
        <RegNumber>NP191382</RegNumber>
        <Year>2014</Year>
        <Mileage>154887.0</Mileage>
        <Price>299950.0</Price>
        <Media>
            <Thumb>ccf1474a-79ed-48c4-9913-b390bc06fddc</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/ccf1474a-79ed-48c4-9913-b390bc06fddc</Pic>
            <Thumb>f23359cd-420a-46a6-aedf-46bf574e83f3</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/f23359cd-420a-46a6-aedf-46bf574e83f3</Pic>
            <Thumb>d300a13e-47a7-446a-8139-7c72d67c423c</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/d300a13e-47a7-446a-8139-7c72d67c423c</Pic>
            <Thumb>a098f3eb-c0de-49e5-b349-a9da58035d09</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/a098f3eb-c0de-49e5-b349-a9da58035d09</Pic>
            <Thumb>4551cb8e-7ef2-4307-9e03-985dc4c7ae6b</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/4551cb8e-7ef2-4307-9e03-985dc4c7ae6b</Pic>
            <Thumb>3f9e73df-ade1-49a9-920d-4122f0439f3a</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/3f9e73df-ade1-49a9-920d-4122f0439f3a</Pic>
            <Thumb>7c76c64b-9ead-4712-a57c-2bee30f1e6e2</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/7c76c64b-9ead-4712-a57c-2bee30f1e6e2</Pic>
            <Thumb>4055da15-1ccc-40e1-8e13-32dade2aafe5</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/4055da15-1ccc-40e1-8e13-32dade2aafe5</Pic>
            <Thumb>e5a6b77b-dade-4c2f-800c-77988a3d0a83</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/e5a6b77b-dade-4c2f-800c-77988a3d0a83</Pic>
        </Media>
        <Colour>White</Colour>
        <AdvertId>b3beab43909043d6a8c086cd223ffd3b</AdvertId>
        <StockNumber>13302</StockNumber>
        <AdditionalText>Great condition with spare keys included</AdditionalText>
        <FuelType>Diesel</FuelType>
        <TransmissionType>Manual</TransmissionType>
        <TransmissionDriveType>4x2</TransmissionDriveType>
        <Doors>4</Doors>
        <BodyType>Double Cab</BodyType>
    </row>
    <row>
        <NewUsed>used</NewUsed>
        <Make>VOLKSWAGEN</Make>
        <Model>GOLF</Model>
        <Derivative>GTI</Derivative>
        <MMCode>64045900</MMCode>
        <RegNumber>YRY546GP</RegNumber>
        <Year>2009</Year>
        <Mileage>116000.0</Mileage>
        <Price>189950.0</Price>
        <Media>
            <Thumb>b554d5da-d0cd-4c80-bc57-d75c7bfaf782</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/b554d5da-d0cd-4c80-bc57-d75c7bfaf782</Pic>
            <Thumb>73064b26-4322-4de9-b78b-863296f9688a</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/73064b26-4322-4de9-b78b-863296f9688a</Pic>
            <Thumb>7d9e2c73-535a-4cde-bb5b-d04af6fb1289</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/7d9e2c73-535a-4cde-bb5b-d04af6fb1289</Pic>
            <Thumb>51144896-3837-4b70-b767-c34021af9d07</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/51144896-3837-4b70-b767-c34021af9d07</Pic>
            <Thumb>5915d1d5-8e84-4cbc-b7cf-d2131f8fb880</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/5915d1d5-8e84-4cbc-b7cf-d2131f8fb880</Pic>
            <Thumb>e052992a-21bc-4473-ab5d-ecae8f50c628</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/e052992a-21bc-4473-ab5d-ecae8f50c628</Pic>
            <Thumb>cebea6d3-bb2a-4389-b132-3cb9a70d5da5</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/cebea6d3-bb2a-4389-b132-3cb9a70d5da5</Pic>
            <Thumb>039034b9-db10-4c27-857d-0e071212949d</Thumb>
            <Pic>https://i.autotrader.co.za/merlin-image-server/view/039034b9-db10-4c27-857d-0e071212949d</Pic>
        </Media>
        <Colour>Silver</Colour>
        <AdvertId>4b2fc17fb8574b70a030db286c76aba0</AdvertId>
        <StockNumber>13498</StockNumber>
        <AdditionalText>GOOD CONDITION WITH FULL SERVICE HISTORY AND SPARE KEY INCLUDED</AdditionalText>
        <FuelType>Petrol</FuelType>
        <TransmissionType>Manual</TransmissionType>
        <TransmissionDriveType>FWD</TransmissionDriveType>
        <Doors>5</Doors>
        <BodyType>Hatchback</BodyType>
    </row>
```

I am able to retrieve all tags fine, except the 'Pic' tags within the 'Media' tags.
My Code is as follows:

```
private XmlDocument GetRootLevelServiceDocument(string serviceEndPoint, string oAuthToken)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = CreateHttpRequest(serviceEndPoint,
                oAuthToken);
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {

                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            string r = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                            doc.LoadXml(r);
                            XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/root/row");
                            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
                            {
                                string img = "";
                                double install = 3000;
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<div class='inventory margin-bottom-20 clearfix scroll_effect fadeIn'><a class='inventory' href='inventory-listing.html'>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<div class='title'>"+ xn["Year"].InnerText +" "+ xn["Make"].InnerText  +" " + xn["Model"].InnerText + " " + xn["Derivative"].InnerText+ "</div>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<img src='"+ img + "' class='preview' alt='Image'>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<table class='options-primary'><tr><td class='option primary'>Mileage:</td>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<td class='spec'>"+ xn["Mileage"].InnerText + "km</td>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "</tr><tr><td class='option primary'>Colour:</td><td class='spec'>"+ xn["Colour"].InnerText + "</td>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "</tr><tr><td class='option primary'>Transmission:</td><td class='spec'>" + xn["TransmissionType"].InnerText + "</td></tr><tr>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<td class='option primary'>Fuel:</td><td class='spec'>" + xn["FuelType"].InnerText + "</td></tr></table>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<table class='options-secondary'><tr><td class='option secondary'>YOU GET:</td></tr><tr><td class='spec'>- A FREE full tank of Fuel</td>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "</tr><tr><td class='spec'>- ...</td></tr><tr><td class='spec'>- ...</td></tr></table>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<img src='images/firstcar.jpg' alt='image' class='carfax' />";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<div class='view-video gradient_button' data-youtube-id='3oh7PBc33dk'><i class='fa fa-video-camera'></i>Finance Now</div><div class='price'><b>Full Price: R" + xn["Price"].InnerText + "</b><br>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<div class='figure'>R"+install+".00 pm<br></div><div class='tax'>Pay Less? Ask us how!</div></div>";
                                divVehicles.InnerHtml += "<div class='view-details gradient_button'><i class='fa fa-plus-circle'></i> View Details </div><div class='clearfix'></div> </a></div>";
                            }
                            xmlDoc = doc;
                          //  test.InnerHtml =  Server.HtmlEncode(doc.InnerXml);
                       }
                    }
                }

                return xmlDoc;

            }
```

What is the correct manner to access the "" tags? Forgive my ignorance.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath to select the elements you need. Here is a simple example using XElement.

Update: Added selection by row

```
XElement xmlData = XElement.Load("media.xml");
var mediaNodes = xmlData.XPathSelectElements(@"/row/Media");
foreach (var mediaElement in mediaNodes)
{
   var picElements = mediaElement.XPathSelectElements("Pic");
   foreach (var picElement in picElements)
   {
      var picValue = picElement.Value;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million, but see, the thing is, I need to somehow do this inside that existing foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList) loop, as I only want Pic tags for that row tag. Not sure if I'm being clear enough. In other words, I need xmlData to consist of only be for one row, and then be able to iterate through the pic tags.

Comment: I've modified my answer. You can call subselects on the current XPath node

Comment: This returns all the Media Nodes within the document. I need to limit xmlData to the current node in the NodeList denoted xn. What could I possibly change "media.xml" to in order to load just that row portion of the xml and thereafter iterate through the media node as you suggest above? 
I have tried passing innerXML to a XElement variable, but it picks up all tags except the media tag.

Comment: Just change the first XPath query to /row. Then iterate over Media.

Answer (score 1):

Try using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<Car> cars = doc.Descendants("row").Select(x => new Car() {
               newUser = (string)x.Element("NewUsed"),
               make = (string)x.Element("Make"),
               model = (string)x.Element("Model"),
               derivative = (string)x.Element("Derivative"),
               code = (string)x.Element("MMCode"),
               registrationNumber = (string)x.Element("RegNumber"),
               year = (int)x.Element("Year"),
               mileage = (decimal)x.Element("Mileage"),
               price = (decimal)x.Element("Price"),
               pictures = x.Element("Media").Elements().Select((y,i) => new { value = (string)y, i = i})
                  .GroupBy(y => y.i / 2)
                  .GroupBy(y => (string)y.FirstOrDefault().value, z => (string)z.Last().value)
                  .ToDictionary(y => y.Key, z => z.FirstOrDefault())

            }).ToList();


        }

    }
    public class Car
    {
        public string newUser { get; set; }
        public string make { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public string derivative { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string registrationNumber { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
        public decimal mileage { get; set; }
        public decimal price { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> pictures { get; set; }
    }
}
```